# Revoke Modify (INSERT UPDATE Delete Truncate) on a table Cassandra DSE

Tags: cassandra, truncate, dse, sql-revoke

I have users that I do not want them to truncate from a table in DSE, I used ***revoke MODIFY  on  ALL KEYSPACES from USER;***
I even used ***Restrict*** but still, the user can truncate. Is there anything I am missing ? is there any setting in Cassandra.yaml?
The command I used to see all the permissions granted or revoked on a user is
List all of user;  or  SELECT role, resource, restricted FROM system_auth.role_permissions
WHERE role = 'user';
I would create a role and restrict truncation but they still ca truncate.
[screen shot of the list all of the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzjKb.png)

Comment: The modify permission controls the truncation permissions, although do remember that revoke does not invalid cached credentials and permissions. Can you perform a `LIST ALL PERMISSIONS ON yourTable OF yourRoleOrUser` and include that in the question. There could be an inherited permission you are not seeing from a role.

Comment: How can I find that out? I am restricting on a keyspace level which is the highest level and everything should inherit from it. Thank you Andrew for your help.

Comment: The list permission command I included above

Comment: I don't see anything that tells me or I am not understanding. There are four columns (Permission, granted, restricted, grantable)  which one indicates the inherited permissions.

Comment: TRUNCATE is the separate permission only in the DSE 6.8

Comment: How can I resolve this @AlexOtt